# laravel 5 Relationship has one

Tags: laravel

```
User table

id | name | user_type | email           | password
1  | John | 1         | john@gmail.com  | something
2  | Roy  | 1         | roy@gmail.com   | something
3  | Rax  | 1         | Rax@gmail.com   | something
4  | Ren  | 1         | ren@gmail.com   | something

AssignUser Table

id | user_id      | assign_to_math | assign_to_chemistry 
1  | 3            | 2               | 1
2  | 4            | 1               | 2
```

So, here is users table where four users are avail
Now in assign table first row Rax is assign tuitoin for math to Roy and chemistry to John

I want to get the detail of john and roy with relation

I tried in User models

```
public function getInfoFormathTutor(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\AssignUser', 'id', 'assign_to_math');
    }
```

It return for me null value don't know why please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your `App\AssignUser` model look like?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public function getInfoFormathTutor(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\AssignUser', 'assign_to_math', 'id');
}
```